# Set multiple classpath in classpath variable

Tags: java, jdbc, classpath

I wanted to set permanent path for OdbcDriver, I have already one path set in classpath variable which is pointing to lib folder of jre so i can not remove that. I tried adding the second path fr OracleDriver using semicolon and tried with colon as well but I am getting a runtime time

```
classNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to execute your java program using a jar? If so, package the drive you want in that jar. Otherwise, please clarify the question

Comment: No, I am not using a jar yet. I have a simple program to connect to oracle database using type 4 drivers and so I need to set classpath of type 4 driver, there is already one classpath set in my classpath environment variable and I tried adding classpath of OracleDriver by adding a semicolon next to the previous classpath and added path to oracle driver but it looks like it never gets to the path that is given next to first one and uses only the first classpath and on running the program it just gives run time class not found exception

Answer (score 0):

Try executing it this way

`java -cp .;completePathToYourDriver/ojdbc14.jar  yourClassName`